# AzureBlobStorage Implementation in 4.4 Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to figure out how to use AzureBlobStorage in the new 4.4 bot framework.  All the samples utilize MemoryStorage which is not ideal for a production bot.  What's the best approach for initializing AzureBloblStorage in Startup.cs?

Answer (score 1):

Memory storage is used for testing purposes only and is not intended for production use. Persistent storage types, such as database storage, are best for production bots. Make sure to set storage to Cosmos DB or Blob Storage before publishing your bot.

In order to initialize Azure Blob Storage in Startup.cs, you can add the following code in your Startup.cs file:

```
// If using Blob Storage. Fill these connection details in from configuration.
var accountName = "<ACCOUNT-NAME>";
var accountKey = "<ACCOUNT-KEY>";
var container = "<your-blob-storage-container-name>";

// Add the implementation through dependency injection (as Scoped because Azure Storage client is not thread safe.)
services.AddScoped<IStore>(_ => new BlobStore(accountName, accountKey, container));
```

Your complete Startup.cs file would look like this example file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            // Create the credential provider to be used with the Bot Framework Adapter.
            services.AddSingleton<ICredentialProvider, ConfigurationCredentialProvider>();

            // Create the Bot Framework Adapter with error handling enabled. 
            services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();

            // Create the storage we'll be using for the Dialog state. 
            // If using Blob Storage. Fill these connection details in from configuration.
             var accountName = "<ACCOUNT-NAME>";
             var accountKey = "<ACCOUNT-KEY>";
             var container = "<your-blob-storage-container-name>";
            // Add the implementation through dependency injection (as Scoped because Azure Storage client is not thread safe.)
             services.AddScoped<IStore>(_ => new BlobStore(accountName, accountKey, container));

            // The Dialog that will be run by the bot.
            services.AddSingleton<RootDialog>();

            // Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
            services.AddTransient<IBot, ScaleoutBot<RootDialog>>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the documentation: see this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#implementation-1

The latest class is `AzureBlobStorage`, you can have a look to the sources [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/AzureBlobStorage.cs)

In a few words:

- Use Nuget package `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure`
- Add reference to `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure` in your `Startup.cs`
- Add the following:

Code sample:

```
// Create the storage we'll be using for User and Conversation state. (Memory is great for testing purposes.)
//services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();
var blobStorage = new AzureBlobStorage("connectionString", "container");
services.AddSingleton<IStorage>(blobStorage);
```

There you go!